# Pandas Excelwriter Diverging Color Data Bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I've been fairly successful in conditionally formatting my excel file using pandas/excelwriter

However, I am having trouble create diverging colored databars, like the ones that can be create in excel:

[image]

I've tried to set a min and max color:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('G2:I80'{'type':'data_bar','min_color':'red','max_color':'green'})
```

But the result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in XlsxWriter version 1.0.4. See the databar [Conditional Formatting Options](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#conditional-format-options).

For you case you could do something like this:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('G2:I80',
                             {'type': 'data_bar',
                              'min_color': 'red',
                              'max_color':'green',
                              'data_bar_2010': True,
                              })
```

Comment: Can this be done in ```openpyxl``` ? If you happen to know

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem here:
https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/501#issuecomment-378630647

There is attached worksheet.txt file that needs to be replaced
(rename file's extension from .txt to .py)

In order to use it just add:
To add conditional_format just use:

```
worksheet.conditional_format("<RANGE>"),
     { 'guid': "<GUID>",
       'type': 'data_bar_bi_directional',
       'bar_color': '#8DB4E3',
       'min_type':'min',
       'max_type':'max'
      })
```

`<RANGE>` - replace with a range of cells that need to be extended with bi-directional data bars
`<GUID>` - replace it with unique GUID